# Volume between under parabaloid

Tags: integration

Suppose I want to find the volume between $z=2x^2+3y^2 $and $ z=4 $.
Is there a way finding that with a double integral?
I tried to use $4-2x^2-3y^2$ inside the integral and then convert it to polar coordinates...

Comment: The expression to integrate is correct, but transforming into polar coords seems wrong to me – the paraboloid is not a surface of revolution... Try integrating in cartesian coordinates instead, but you need to find the area of integration first.

Comment: If I try to do it with polar coordinates I get $p^2=4/(2+sin^2(\theta))$ Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A volume is usually calculated with a triple integral, and I suggest you do the same. More or less by definition, the volume of object $O$ is

$$\iiint_O 1dxdydz$$

In your case, that woud become

$$\int_0^4 \int_{-\frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt 3}}^{\frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{3}}}\int_{-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \sqrt{z-3y^2}}^{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \sqrt{z-3y^2}}  1dx dy dz$$

Comment: Yes I know that, but I was asking myself if it was possible to solve it with a double integral :p

Comment: @AyoubRossi It is possible, if you manage to interpret the object as the volume under a function. In that case you need to shift the paraboloid down to the plane $z=4$.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of the solid of interest $E$ is,

$$\iint_{D} (4-2x^2-3y^2) dA$$

Where $D$ is the projection of the solid $E$ onto the $xy$ plane. That is, the region $2x^2+3y^2 \leq 4$ in the $xy$ plane. Or,

$$\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}\right)^2 \leq 1$$

To evaluate the double integral, use the modified polar transformation:

$$x=\sqrt{2}\,r\cos(\theta)$$

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}\,r\sin (\theta)$$

Whose Jacobian is $\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\,r$. Hence the volume  is,

$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}r (4-4r^2) dr d\theta$$

$$=4\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$$

$$=\frac{4}{3}\pi\sqrt{6}$$

---

The above transformation can be thought of as combining two transformations.

$$X=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$Y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}$$

Then

$$X=r\cos(\theta)$$

$$Y=r\sin(\theta)$$

---

At a height of $z \geq 0$, a slice of our solid of interest (parallel to the xy plane) has elliptical area $A(z)=\pi\sqrt{\frac{z}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{z}{3}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}z$.

So the volume of the solid is,

$$V=\int_{0}^{4} A(z) dz$$

$$=\frac{8\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$$

$$=\frac{4}{3}\pi \sqrt{6}$$

Which matches the result from the double integral.

Comment: only this answer answers OP's question so far.

Comment: Thanks @CiaPan looks much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

If it's a **volume** it will be a triple integral ! The parametrization is $$\left\{(\frac{r}{\sqrt 2}\cos\theta ,\frac{r}{\sqrt 3}\sin\theta , z)\mid r\in z\in[0,4], r\in [0,\sqrt z]\right\}$$